# NoHostAvailable connecting to Cassandra from python in Databricks environment

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

hostname = ['contact_point_name']
port = '10350'
cluster = Cluster(hostname, control_connection_timeout=None, port = port)
session = cluster.connect()
```

Error: NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'23.96.242.234:10350': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds), last_host=None')})

Comment: is it Cassandra API of CosmosDB? or standalone Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted indicates that it couldn't connect to the cluster at all.

The possible causes are:

- There is no network connectivity to the node(s).
- The node is not listening on port `10350` on IP `23.96.242.234`

Cassandra is listening for client connections on IP `rpc_address` and port `native_transport_port` (default is `9042`). Confirm that you have the correct details and ensure there's connectivity between your machine and the cluster using Linux tools such as `telnet` or `nc`. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, The Ip address is correct. but Im getting a timed out error always for any method. my aim is to try and delete records from azure cosmos cassandra api through pyspark. Can you help?

Comment: If it's CosmosDB then you probably need to configure SSL/TLS. You'll need to consult the docs for details or get in contact with Azure support. Cheers!